# A change made locally to observer in development mode not happening when deployed to production?

Tags: magento2

After updating the code I ran the following:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento deploy:mode:set -s production
bin/magento index:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

The change was made in an Observer

The problem is that no matter what I do, even disabling the module entirely the change does not happen on a dropdown.

Is there more I should be doing for a complete deploy? Maybe Opcache is keeping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `opcache`

You need to flush it with [Opcache reset](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-clear-php-opcache/)

Answer (score 1):

I found running the below always helped clear the site and load the latest PHP code

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```